# Trigger for two databases

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have two databases, db1 and db2, 
each has a able. The two databases have the same data in each table.
For the databases remain the same, I need a trigger that causes, when inserting a new data table in db1, this same data is inserted into db2 table simultaneously, thus keeping the two databases always equal.
There tables are equal.

Comment: Perhaps using replication not triggers ?  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html

Comment: You cannot do this with triggers alone, as in PostgreSQL one database cannot directly access tables from another. You'll want to use dblink, or use a replication system.

Answer (score 0):

Google [Slony](http://slony.info/), that's it, now you have triggers and replicas.

The other way to do it, would be the [streaming replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication).